# XMPP protocol allow registration using protocol

Tags: xmpp

I want to write own XMPP client. I have jabber server. Is it real use XMPP library only register on server programaticaly?

I want to generate login, password prog-ly, then register prog-ly on server and start to chat. Or XMPP protocol doesn't allow have registering operation?

Answer (score 2):

Registering an account via the XMPP protocol is known as [in-band registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html), defined in XEP-0077.

However, not all servers support this, or they have it disabled, or impose time/IP limits, as this makes it easy for people writing spambots (which hopefully you are **not** doing) to easily create multiple accounts automatically.

Like with most XMPP extensions, you can use [Service Discovery](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html#disco) to determine whether a server supports in-band registration.